# How would a compiler interpret `if(!(a=10))`?

Tags: c, if-statement, negation

I have a homework assignment in which I believe the professor has made a typo, typing `if(!(a=10))` instead of `if(!(a==10))`. However, when asked if this was typo, she told me to "assume that the equations are correct and give your answer." Specifically, the assignment is to describe the behavior of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
      int a = 100;
      while (1) {
          if (!(a=10)) {
              break;
          } 
      }
      return 0; 
}
```

If the offensive code read `(!(a==10))` then the program would enter the `if` loop, reach the `break` and exit both loops, which makes sense for a beginner-level course in C programming.

However, if, truly, the code is meant to read `(!(a=10))` then I don't know what the compiler will interpret that to mean. I do know that the code compiles, and when you run it in UNIX, it just allows you to input whatever you want using the keyboard, like say the number "7", and then you press enter and it moves to a new line, and you can enter "dog", and move to a new line, and on and on and it never exits back to the command line. So (1) how would the compiler interpret `(!(a=10))`? And (2) why does the program allow you to just continue to input entries forever?

Thanks!

Comment: The input stuff doesn't mean anything - Unix will always allow you to type stuff and buffer it until it's read later.  What's significant is that the program never exits - it is looping infinitely, so you can conclude that the `break;` is never taken.  Now you have to figure out why not.

Comment: Hint: `a=10` is an expression and has a value.  What is that value?  Read carefully about how the `=` operator works.

Comment: `!(a=10)` will always be `false`, in C, everything other than 0 is considered to be `true` and `=` assigns `10` to `a`. So you can consider it as `!10` which is `false`.

Comment: I doubt it is typo. It's a trick question.

Comment: Assignment to a variable is not an "equation". Your teacher either does not speak "math English" or else English as such.  In C, the `==` comparison is closer to a mathematical equation, since the values of two expressions are being equated. If someone believes that `a = 3` in C program is an "equation", and otherwise knows how to use that word correctly, they almost certainly made a typo.

Comment: So just to be sure I'm interpreting precisely correctly: The program does overwrite `a` using the statement `a=10`, then it interprets the truth value of this statement as `TRUE`, which is then given to the `!` operator, the output of which is `FALSE`, and that is the precise reason why the `if` loop is never entered?

Comment: @1Teaches2Learn: No, see my answer below.

Comment: @InQusitive Your answer and OPs comment seem to match (assuming "if loop"=="then of the if"). What am I missing?

Comment: @1Teaches2Learn Yes you're correct, just remember that `0` is considered `false` in C and anything other than `0` is `true`. So `if(0)` is like saying `if(false)`, and `if(10)` is like saying `if(true)`.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I think 'truth value of this statement as TRUE' he meant  a == 10 as TRUE. But here it is not giving TRUE or FALSE, but the actual value of it. Did I read incorrectly?

Comment: @InQusitive I meant, per JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer's comment, that the program will interpret the statement `a=10` to be TRUE so that `!(a=10)` is FALSE. Perhaps it is more accurately the case that the statement `a=10` alone does not have a truth value, but only when given to the `!` operator is the program forced to try to make a decision about the truth value of `a=10`?

Comment: @1Teaches2Learn:  Whether you are giving `!` or not it will consider the value for taking decision.

Comment: @1Teaches2Learn The `true` and `false` were to actually help you understand it better, as I've said, `if(0)` is like saying `if(false)` and `if(10)` is like saying `if(true)`. `!10` is actually `0`. As InQusitive said, "Whether you are giving `!` or not, it'll consider the value for taking decision.".

Comment: Got it. That all makes sense. Thank you all so much for your help.

Comment: @InQusitive Ah I see. Yes, it can be read like you did. It might however also be a correct understanding "the truth value of this statement as TRUE" is "(10 != 0) == true". Both is possible, thanks for making me aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question,
What's the meaning of `if( !(a=10) ){break;}`,
It's equivalent to

`a = 10; if(!a) {break;}`

For a value of `10` `!a` will be `0` and it never breaks the `while` loop.
In this particular example, if you assign `if(!(a=0))`, then it will exit the loop;

For the second question, there is no code present in your example.
But first question's answer can be extended here as the loop never breaks it keeps on asking the input values.

Comment: Thank you. In particular, the point that the loop will reach the `break` if the assignment were changed to `if(!(a=0))` is very helpful to my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard ([6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators ¶5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p5))

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of
> its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
> compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression `!E` is
> equivalent to `(0==E)`.

So according to the quote the if statement

```
if (!(a=10)) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( a = 10 ) == 0 ) {
```

As the value of the assignment sub-expression, `a = 10` is equal to `10` that is it is not equal to `0` then the condition of the if statement evaluates to logical false and the sub-statement of the if statement will not get the control and you will have an infinite while loop.

In fact, you can rewrite this while loop

```
  while (1) {
      if (!(a=10)) {
          break;
      } 
  }
```

the following way with the same effect

```
  while ( ( a = 10 ) ) {}
```

or just

```
  while ( ( a = 10 ) );
```

or more simply:

```
while ( a != 0 );
```

because what is important is that within the while loop the variable `a` does become equal to 0.

Comment: What's the character 5 in "5 The result of "

Comment: @InQusitive It is the number of the paragraph within the referenced section of the Standard.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
      while (1) {
          if (!(a=10)) {
              break;
          } 
      }
```

as `!(a = 10)` is always zero (false) it is equivalent of:

```
      while (1) {
      }
```